# error with unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, mathematical-optimization

I was doing an optimization problem to find the minimum. The process is not important, and the logic behind my code is correct (verified by my supervisor). However, although the code works in others environment, it does not work in mine. It always shows the unhashable numpy array error.

Here is my code. If anyone could please help me with it, I would be much appreciate it.

```
import math
import random
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from sympy.vector import *

x1,x2=sp.symbols('x1 x2')
f1=x1*x1+x2*x2
df1x1=sp.diff(f1,x1)
df1x2=sp.diff(f1,x2)

gradf1 = [df1x1,df1x2]

def f(x):
    return f1.evalf(subs={x1:x[0],x2:x[1]})

def gradf(x):
    return [df1x1.evalf(subs={x1:x[0],x2:x[1]}),df1x2.evalf(subs={x1:x[0],x2:x[1]})]

p=[[],[]]
def Momentum(f,gradf,x0,alphi,beta):
    x=x0
    v=np.array([0,0])
    while True:
        g=np.array(gradf(x))
        v=beta*v-alphi*g
        xx=(np.array(x)+v).tolist()
        print(xx,f(xx))
        if f(xx)>f(x):
            break
        x=xx
        p[0].append(float(x[0]))
        p[1].append(float(x[1]))
    return x

X1 = np.arange(-1.5, 3.5 + 0.05, 0.05)
X2 = np.arange(-1.0, 4.0 + 0.05, 0.05)
[x1, x2] = np.meshgrid(X1, X2)
ff =x1**2/5+x2**2
plt.contour(x1, x2, ff, 20) # contour plot
x0=[2,1]
p[0].append(x0[0])
p[1].append(x0[1])

xmin=Momentum(f,gradf,[0,1],1,1)
print('xmin:',xmin,',fmin:',f(xmin))

plt.plot(p[0],p[1], 'g*-') # traces for convergence
plt.show()
```

Comment: The problem is that you use `x1` (and `x2`) for 3 different kinds of variables.  Please use unique names every time your variable gets another meaning. Especially, don't use the same variable name that sometimes gets a symbolic sympy variable and then a numpy array.

Comment: You should have shown the full error with traceback.  And maybe even made an attempt at understanding the error (even if incomplete).  But I agree with @JohanC, that the error probably occurs in the {x1:x[0]...}` line, the only one with a `dict` (which using hashing for keys).  That line works when `x1` is a `sympy.symbol`, as initially defined.  But not when `x1` is the array in the `Momentum` call.  Be extra careful when mixing `sympy` and `numpy`.  There are lots of ways this can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The full error with traceback:

```
In [5]: xmin=Momentum(f,gradf,[0,1],1,1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-7180eedc63ce>", line 1, in <module>
    xmin=Momentum(f,gradf,[0,1],1,1)
  File "<ipython-input-1-e190aed0f5ac>", line 25, in Momentum
    g=np.array(gradf(x))
  File "<ipython-input-1-e190aed0f5ac>", line 18, in gradf
    return [df1x1.evalf(subs={x1:x[0],x2:x[1]}),df1x2.evalf(subs={x1:x[0],x2:x[1]})]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Changing the array names

```
 [xx1, xx2] = np.meshgrid(X1, X2)
```

allows `Momentum` to run, though it does so very slowly (even without the `print`).  I haven't studied this code, but running `sympy` expressions repeatedly, is quite inefficient.  For better numeric results, use `sympy.lambdify` to create a numpy function that can work entirely with numbers.

Without the interference of the array redefinition, `grad` does run:

```
In [19]: timeit gradf([0,1])
129 µs ± 1.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```